# Storing files in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm facing a problem of cleanliness and safety.

I'm using VichUploaderBundle to upload files, so I have to configure where to store them.

```
uri_prefix: ???
upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/???'
```

Which places would be both accessible and secure (not accessible via the url) ?

thanks for your advices,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them literally everywhere you want, as soon as not in the  `public` folder, I guess.

For example you create a `/data` folder and stores them all here.

You store the file's info with the local path and other info you want in a database.
Then when you want to access them, you search the file with PHP and return the file content to display it to the browser (via a URL including the id of the file info in database).

Is that what you meant ?